# ExactTarget: AMPscript - display limited content

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have 3 data extensions: 
subscribers list + lookup file with 6 columns some of them with ID numbers others empty + another lookup file with content.

I'm looping through the first lookup file using LookUp Rows to find all the IDs, then I use these IDs to identify the copy from the columns from the secondary LookUp file using LookUp (first column has the IDs).

In the HTML I only need to display the first 3 blocks of content I found (first 3 non-empty columns).

How can I do that with AMPscript?

Answer (score 1):

If you question is how would you display the first 3 rows from the dataset you would want to setup a counter variable (@rowCount) to track which row number was matched to each record in the record set. Then, use a if statement within a "for loop" to display records 1 thru 3 using the record

```
<span style="display:none;">%%[
/* Using lookup rows function to return a rowset of related to use */
var @lookupValue, @numRowsToReturn, @rows, @rowCount
set @lookupValue = "A"  /* use case here - For all records, the 'Group' column has a default value of 'A' */
set @numRowsToReturn = 0  /* 0 means all */
set @rows = LookupOrderedRows("YOURDATAEXTENSION", @numRowsToReturn, "ID","Group", @lookupValue)
set @rowCount = RowCount(@rows)
]%%</span>

<table>
<tr>
<th>Num</th>
<th>ID</th>
<td>Important Field</th>
</tr>

<span style="display:none;">%%[
if @rowCount > 0 then

for @i = 1 to @rowCount do ]%%</span>
<tr>
<td>%%=v(@i)=%%</td>
<td>%%=Field(@row, "ID")=%%</td>
</tr>

<span style="display:none;">%%[
next @i
endif 
]%%</span>
</table>
```

However, if you are trying to display **only records where certain fields are not blank**, you would use the if statement and not empty function to check for those cases individually (i.e. if not Empty(@importantFieldIsPresent) then ) and use your counter variable to count up from 1 to 3 for every occurrence where you saw all your desired set of columns (first 3 non-empty columns) appear. You will need a compound if statement to handle all three columns for non-empty conditions.

i.e.

```
<span style="display:none;">%%[
var @myImportantFieldIsPresent

if @rowCount > 0 then

for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

   @myImportantFieldIsPresent = Field(@row, "MyImportantField")

   if not Empty(@myImportantFieldIsPresent) then

 ]%%</span>
<tr>
<td>%%=v(@i)=%%</td>
<td>%%=Field(@row, "ID")=%%</td>
<td>%%=v(@myImportantFieldIsPresent)=%%</td>
</tr>

<span style="display:none;">%%[
  endif
next @i
endif 
]%%</span>
</table>
```